# How to set the blur level of a view background

Tags: android, android-drawable

To set the transparency level of a view background we use

```
mView.getBackground().setAlpha(mViewTransparencyLvl);
```

How to set the blur level of a view background?

Knowing that the background is a shape drawable not an image. Knowing that the user controls the blur degree. Knowing that this view is over part of another view.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Android doesn't provide this functionality for UI elements as iOS does. It's not part of the UI rendering engine and to obtain these kind of effects you need to use third-party libraries which will essentially take a snapshot of the drawing cache, reduce its size for a faster processing and then put the generated bitmap into a view.

Here are some example libraries:

- [BlurrView](https://github.com/Dimezis/BlurView)
- [Blurry](https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry)

Please bear in mind that this will have a serious performance hit on mid-low end phones.

Comment: Thank you @Cristian for your answer, but such technique is not desired ... What about WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND ? is it possible to use it and control the blur degree?

Comment: From Android Docs: `FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND`
This constant was deprecated in API level 14. Blurring is no longer supported.

Comment: There is no "native" way of achieving what are you looking for. Only by libraries or implementing custom code for your drawables, to blur the content. Look at `RenderScript`.

Comment: in 2022 , for those people who want to use these two libraries, they have serious problems on the page that has a lot of views or recyclerview .  I did not find any native way. Android...